# I want to get the transactionID of Square POS API

Tags: square, square-connect

I am trying to add a payment function to the iOS application using the Square POS API.

After "Square POS" payment is completed, I am concerned about the case where I can not receive the callback.

If I could not receive a callback, how can I get a `TransactionID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it should be rare that something goes wrong when returning to your application, if the need arises, you can find your past transactions using Square's Transactions API. By calling the `ListTransactions` endpoint, you can see the `TransactionID`, among many other attributes of the Transaction.

Please see https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-listtransactions for more information.

Comment: Thank you for answering.

Can I find the Transaction (or Tender) corresponding to the request from the `ListTransactions` ?

For example, can i make it correspond by setting a unique value for `note` of SCCAPIRequest?

Comment: If you enter a note in the POS app ("Notes and Quantity"), it will be viewable via the V1 endpoint: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#get-payments under Payment -> itemizations -> notes.

If you add the note during the choosing of payment method (after clicking Charge and adding Optional Note), it should be viewable in the V2 Transaction > Tender > note.